# Spark application runs in local but not in cluster

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

Hi I am new to Spark and Scala and I am trying to write some code to fit a RandomForestClassifier. When I run it in local mode everything is fine but I get an error when I am trying to run it in a cluster with two workers. I run the program through IntelliJ Idea and this is the error. The version of Scala is 2.10.6 and the version of spark is 2.1.1

I have edited the trace of the error

```
    17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 37625.
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.5:37625
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.5, 37625, None)
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.5:37625 with 884.7 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.5, 37625, None)
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.5, 37625, None)
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.5, 37625, None)
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20170701182854-0000/0 on worker-20170701181736-192.168.1.5-46243 (192.168.1.5:46243) with 4 cores
17/07/01 18:28:54 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170701182854-0000/0 on hostPort 192.168.1.5:46243 with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
17/07/01 18:28:55 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170701182854-0000/0 is now RUNNING
17/07/01 18:28:55 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
17/07/01 18:28:55 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/apostolis/IdeaProjects/WordCount/spark-warehouse/'.
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 236.5 KB, free 884.5 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 22.9 KB, free 884.4 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.5:37625 (size: 22.9 KB, free: 884.7 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at CountWords.scala:31
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 236.5 KB, free 884.2 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 22.9 KB, free 884.2 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.5:37625 (size: 22.9 KB, free: 884.7 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from textFile at CountWords.scala:37
17/07/01 18:28:56 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112) with 1 output partitions
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112)
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at map at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112), which has no missing parents
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.6 KB, free 884.2 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.6 KB, free 884.2 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.5:37625 (size: 2.6 KB, free: 884.7 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at map at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112)
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
17/07/01 18:28:57 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (192.168.1.5:54248) with ID 0
17/07/01 18:28:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.1.5, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5995 bytes)
17/07/01 18:28:58 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.5:45601 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.1.5, 45601, None)
17/07/01 18:28:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.5:45601 (size: 2.6 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/07/01 18:28:58 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.1.5, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2251)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And here is the code

```
object NewTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://192.168.1.5:7077")
      .appName("RandomForest")
      .getOrCreate()

    case class Record(x1:Int,x2:Int,x3:Int,x4:Int,x5:Int,x6:Int,x7:Int,x8:Int,x9:Int,x10:Int,label:Int)

    val sc=spark.sparkContext

    val raw=sc.textFile("/home/apostolis/Desktop/poker_train.data").map(x=>x.split(',')).map{
      case Array(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,label)=>Record(x1.toInt,x2.toInt,x3.toInt,x4.toInt,x5.toInt,x6.toInt,x7.toInt,x8.toInt,x9.toInt,x10.toInt,label.toInt)
    }

    //raw.foreach(println)

    val raw1=sc.textFile("/home/apostolis/Desktop/poker_test.data").map(x=>x.split(',')).map{
      case Array(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,label)=>Record(x1.toInt,x2.toInt,x3.toInt,x4.toInt,x5.toInt,x6.toInt,x7.toInt,x8.toInt,x9.toInt,x10.toInt,label.toInt)
    }

    var train=raw.map(x=> LabeledPoint(x.label,Vectors.dense(x.x1,x.x2,x.x3,x.x4,x.x5,x.x6,x.x7,x.x8,x.x9,x.x10)))

    var test=raw.map(x=> LabeledPoint(x.label,Vectors.dense(x.x1,x.x2,x.x3,x.x4,x.x5,x.x6,x.x7,x.x8,x.x9,x.x10)))

    //train.foreach(println)


    val treeStrategy=Strategy.defaultStrategy("Classification")
    val numTrees=600
    val featureSubsetStrategy= "auto"
    val categorical=Map[Int,Int]()
    val impurity = "gini"
    val maxDepth = 4
    val maxBins = 32
    //val model=RandomForest.trainClassifier(train,treeStrategy,numTrees,featureSubsetStrategy,seed=1234)
    val model=RandomForest.trainClassifier(train,10,categorical,numTrees,featureSubsetStrategy,impurity,maxDepth,maxBins,seed=124)

    val labels=test.map{
      point => val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
        (point.label,prediction)
    }

    //labels.foreach(println)

    val testerror= labels.filter(r=>r._1!=r._2).count.toDouble / test.count()

    System.out.println(testerror)



  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the version of Spark and Scala on both environment.

Comment: Both environments have scala 2.10.6 and spark 2.1.1 @SandeepSingh

Comment: 1) It would be cool if you provide more lines of stacktrace becides first. It helps to locate place of "explosion". 2) By default spark 2 prebuilt with scala 2.11. Show your build.sbt (or config of whatever build tool you use).

Comment: I have updated the error. In the build.sbt I have scala 2.12.2 but I have scala-sdk 2.10.6 because I had a problem with IntelliJ and scala 2.12.2 @Zernike

Comment: Scala in your system doesn't matter for your project. Only specified in build tool version is applied. So your application is "baked" for 2.12. Other depends on build of spark (with witch version of scala) that deploys (spark-submit) application.